# About nginx. How to make nginx serve files from directories owned by a spcific user?

Tags: nginx, security, web-server

I have seen this many times in ubuntu 16.04 and even in centos 7 that the nginx can even serve files from directories(document root) owned by user root. How to make nginx serve files from directories owned by a spcific user?

I know nginx needs to started by user root so that it can bind to port 80 and 443 but how to limit nginx to only access files owned by simple user and not be able to serve files owned by anyone else specially user root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the virtual host document root so that all files under that directory are such files that can be served to visitors.

If there are some files / directories under that directory that you don't want to serve, then you can set file permissions so that only the owner / group can read the files.

Comment: What i am saying is the document root ownership should be other than root and nginx shouldn't be able to access files owned by root.."user nginx" entry in nginx.conf and nginx can still serve files owned by root in document root.

Comment: Then you need to set permissions to N00, where N are the permissions you want the owner to have. This denies any access for other users.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.. Okay here is the scenario.. worker_processes are running as user "nginx", master process as user "root". Php-fpm pool user & group all nginx.           Now the document root for Nginx is /sites directory , owned by root and Nginx is still serving content from this directory and not showing 403 forbidden error or something.  Is it normal??????

Comment: Yes, it is normal as long as `nginx` user has read permissions on the directory.